# fabricjs: How to make the canvas object (rectangle) always active on mouse:down event also?

Tags: canvas, mouseevent, fabricjs, mouseout

How to make the selection of canvas object ( rectangle) always active even after `mouse:down` event ? I have tried with the `subTargetCheck:true` property; but this property is not fulfilling the said requirement.

```
this.fabricObject = new fabric.Rect({
  left: this.objectSize.left,
  top: this.objectSize.top,
  width: this.objectSize.width,
  height: this.objectSize.height,
  fill: '#ccc',
  padding: 10,
  subTargetCheck: true
});

this.canvas.add(this.fabricObject);
this.fabricObject.center().setCoords();
this.canvas.renderAll();
```

=> Code for set always active

```
this.canvas.on('mouse:down', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target)
  this.canvas.getObjects().map((object:any) => {
    object.set('active', true);
    this.canvas.renderAll();
  })
});
```

=> If i do it for color fill then it is working fine on mouse out event.

```
this.canvas.on('mouse:down', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target)
  this.canvas.getObjects().map((object:any) => {
    object.set('fill', 'green');
    this.canvas.renderAll();
  })
});
```

REF: https://jsfiddle.net/jasie/r3fqu4p6/12/

As in the jsfiddle when click on the square it is going to active and when click out side of square it is going to deactivate... so i want that active too while clicking outside of that square.

Comment: `mouse:out` is when you _move_ your mouse out of the object's boundaries. `mouse:down` is when you _click_ on something. Please edit your post with what you actually need, you're clearly confusing the two.

Comment: Updated my question. Thank you so much for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `canvas.setActiveObject()` to manually set an active object on the canvas.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
var ourRect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    width: 75,
    height: 50,
    fill: "green",
    padding: 10,
    subTargetCheck: true
});

canvas.add(ourRect);

canvas.on("mouse:down", object => {
    canvas.setActiveObject(ourRect);
});
```

Please check this CodeSansbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-60522500-fabric-js-1720-ekocp